# Is a pie-slice technique suitable for evaluating this integral?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to evaluate the integral from 0 to infinity of the integrand x/(x^5+1) by a pie-slice technique. (Let's call that integral "I".) More specifically I'm considering a contour from 0 to R along the real axis, then counter clockwise along a circle segment of radius R from R to R * exp(i*2*pi/5), and finally along a straight line back from there to 0.

Inside the pie-slice there seems to be exactly one singularity of the integrand, namely a simple pole at exp (i*pi/5), and the residue there seems to be 1/(5*exp(i*3*pi/5).

I'm parametrizing the last described portion of the contour by the function t* exp(i*2*pi/5). When I plug that into the integrand, I get I * negative exp(i*2*pi/5), but probably I have to multiply everything with a Jacobian, which gives me I * negative exp(i*4*pi/5).

So I * (1 - exp (i*4*pi/5)) seems to be equal to (2 * pi * i)/(5*exp(i*3*pi/5)), which means that I = 0.660653.

Is this correct? Would it be possible to use a semicircle technique instead, or maybe some technique from real analysis?

Comment: I don't really follow the Jacobian part nor how you got the integral over the other line segment to equal $-I\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{5}\right)$, but the final answer is correct and you parameterized that line segment correctly. I think the semicircular method could work, but the problem is that you would need to evaluate $\operatorname{PV}\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{z}{1+z^{5}}dz$ and the indented path enclosing the pole at $z = -1$. The latter should be simple to calculate, but I don't know how to solve the $\operatorname{PV}$ integral off the top of my head.

Comment: As another approach, you could also factor the denominator, do some nasty partial fractions, and do some substitutions (according to an online calculator, anyways), but the antiderivative is not pretty at all. Also, here's a [Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Accelerator I think that I have to multiply everything with a Jacobian when I change from dz to dt.

Comment: By "Jacobian," do you mean the Jacobian factor $g'(x)$ when doing a substitution for something like $\int_{g\left(a\right)}^{g\left(b\right)}f\left(u\right)du=\int_{a}^{b}f\left(g\left(x\right)\right)g'\left(x\right)dx$? If you parameterize $z = t\exp\left(2\pi i /5\right)$, the integral over the angled line segment should be $\int_{R}^{0}\frac{t\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{5}\right)}{1+\left(t\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{5}\right)\right)^{5}}\cdot\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{5}\right)dt$, which equals $-I\exp\left(\frac{4\pi i}{5}\right)$.

Comment: @Accelerator Yes, the thing with which you multiply everything in a substitution like this is called "Jacobian ", I think.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. I think a pizza slice contour is the best way to solve this.